# multicast to all interfaces (how to set up the routes?)

Tags: linux, iproute, multicast

I want a host to send out multicast traffic to all interfaces, but it seems I can only have one route.

I tried `ip route add 224/4 dev eth0`, and then `ip route add 224/4 dev sit1`, but the second one was not accepted.
Then I deleted the multicast routes and tried `ip route add 224/4 dev eth0`, and then `ip route append 224/4 dev sit1` instead, but it seems only the first route is actually used, even though `ip route show` shows both routes.

Is it possible at all, and if so: How?

Also: What is the effect of `route append` when it seems only the first one is ever used?

Comment: In my recollection, you won't need a route, but you will have to enable multicast on the interfaces. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-enabling_ip_multicast_with_igmp. After that, receiving hosts will report via `igmp` in their broadcast domain through the use of `setsockopt()`, which triggers and outgoing `igmp` packet, causing the receiving interface to forward mcast packets for this group.

Comment: `eth0` had `MULTICAST`, but `sit1` did not. So I used `ip link set multicast on dev sit1` and deleted the multicast routes (`ip route del 224/4` twice). However multicast wasn't sent through `sit1` still (confirmed using `tcpdump`). In `/proc/net/igmp` I see that `lo` and `sit1` use `V3`, while `eth0` uses `V2`.

Comment: You should see `igmp queries` from time to time (destination `224.0.0.x`) in any case. *Only* if a client reports membership to a multicast-group, traffic for this group will be forwarded via the receiving interface.

Comment: to select one interface, adding the adequate route will use it. Else, for multiple interfaces, the actual action of duplicating packets for multicasting (one to many) is performed by a multicast router. The end nodes and applications can send or receive, but don't duplicate (except internally at the node level). The interface flag `mc_forwarding off` is read-only, it requires an actual multicast routing daemon to be running to be toggled on. The probably most simple of these is smcroute, and then I guess `ip mroute` can be used (read-only): the real config is with smcroute.

Comment: But having tested a bit, for local outgoing traffic rather than forwarded traffic I'm not sure that's possible (at least with smcroute). I guess using an additional network namespace so it becomes routed would work around this, but I'd rather have liked it would be directly possible.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained that I want that *because* we have no multicast router, and basically I want to "forward" multicast traffic to another subnet (via `sit1`). At the moment multicast traffic is either sent to `eth0`, or to `sit1`, but not to both.